# C++11 auto variable initialized by nullptr

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, nullptr

What is the type of variable "something" in C++ 11 standard initialized by

```
auto something = nullptr;
```

?

Comment: `decltype(nullptr)` ;)

Comment: `void*`?  `std::nullptr_t`?

Comment: I see it compiles, but is a logical error :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type of that is `std::nullptr_t` which is a single valued type introduced in C++11 to represent a null pointer and which is implicitly convertible to any other pointer type.

Comment: @mdkess: 2.14.7 [lex.nullptr]/1 *The pointer literal is the keyword nullptr. It is a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.* In the standard, the type exists without the need of the value, although I can see implementations using that typedef in a header as an implementation detail. They could also do `typedef delctype(1) int;` if they wanted, as whether the chicken or the egg comes first is just a detail

Comment: Well that makes things confusing.

Comment: @mdkess: What makes what confusing? There is a type `std::nullptr_t` and a keyword `nullptr` that is a *prvalue* of that type. Not too different from a `std::istream` type and a global `std::cin` (except that in the case of `nullptr` it is a keyword, not just a global)

Comment: "I can see implementations using that typedef in a header as an *implementation detail*". I wouldn't say that this is an implementation detail since it's mandatory by the Standard. 18.2[support.types]/9 says "`nullptr_t` *is defined as follows:*
`namespace std { typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t; }`". Anyway, the chicken-and-egg is not an issue for `nullptr`/`nullptr_t`.

Comment: @CassioNeri: Covered by as-if rule. A portable program can't really detect how it's exactly defined.

Comment: @MSalters: I disagree. The as-if rule covers the semantics of the abstract machine defined by the Standard but it doesn't cover the Library. In addition, 18.2 [support.types] says that `<cstddef>` must contain `typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t`. Nevertheless, the as-if rule allows the existence of an unnamed type for which `nullptr_t` is a synonym. IMO the analogy with `auto foo = []{}; typedef decltype(foo) foo_t;` is better than `std::istream` and `std::cin`. Notice that I'm not saying this answer is wrong.

Comment: @Cassio - the meaning of "abstract machine" is not defined in the standard.  In computer science, an abstract machine for a programming language is generally represented as a set of rules (abstractions, semantics, etc) that collectively result in programs written in the language working within intended bounds.   The standard library is defined within the standard, which specifies a set of rules that affect the working of C++ programs.  By that interpretation, the specification of the standard library is part of the abstract machine, and the "as-if" rule would apply to it.